# Problema ao pegar tempo de acesso

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Estou tentando pegar o tempo que o internauta permaneceu na página, no entanto é retornado nada.

Arquivo php principal:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Introdução</title>

<!--<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>-->
<script src="jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript">
var inicio;
$(document).ready(function(){
    inicio = new Date();
    inicio = inicio.getTime();
 
    $(window).unload(function(){
    fim = new Date;
    fim = fim.getTime();
    $.ajax({
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1/time.php',
    data: {'time': fim - inicio},
    success: function(i){$('#demo').html(i);}
    });

    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="demo"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

time.php

```js
<?php
# converter o tempo para um formato legivel
function converter($tempo)
{
    $hora = 0;
    $tempo = $tempo / 1000;
    $ms = str_replace('0.', '', $tempo - floor($tempo));
    if($tempo > 3600)
    {
        $hora = floor($tempo / 3600);
    }
    $tempo = $tempo % 3600;
    $out = str_pad($hora, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . gmdate(':i:s', $tempo) . ($ms ? ".$ms" : '');
    return $out;
}

if(isset($_GET['time'])){
    $file = fopen('time.txt', 'w');
    if($file){
        fwrite($file, converter($_GET['time']));
        fclose($file);
    }
}
?>
```

e por fim:

`time.txt` em branco.

Alguém sabe oque esta de errado?
Preciso muito resolver esse problema.

Comment: Ou só funciona em um sistema?

Comment: O código PHP que cria a função converter e pega os dados da requisição http devem estar no arquivo time.php e não no principal. E você também não precisa definir o div nele. Só o código já basta.

Comment: Testei de todas as maneiras. Igor fiz o que vc mencionou e visitei o time.php mas nada ainda. Coloquei o js dentro de um site e visitei a página time.php e nada ainda. acho que esse código tem algum erro.

Comment: [sendBeacon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) é a solução ideal pra isso, mas não funciona no IE nem Safari. Uma ideia é fazer um long-polling/websocket, seria bem confiável e tem suporte mais amplo. Considere deixar esse tipo de tarefa para o Google Analytics ou Piwik.

Answer (score 0):

Fazer uma requisição AJAX em um evento `unload` não há garantia que será completada. Não tenho certeza se isso depende da conexão ser rápida o suficiente ou se o navegador cancela a requisição.

Mas há uma solução!

Se `async: false` for especificado na requisição, a aba só será fechada ou passará para a próxima página assim que ela for finalizada.

```
jQuery(window).unload(function () {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1/time.php',
        async: false,
        data: { time: fim - inicio }
    });
});
```

Comment: Para complementar, há algumas desvantagens desse método: [é pouco confiável](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3596222/1840019)(em alguns casos os dados não serão enviados) e é síncrono, portanto impacta no carregamento da próxima página.